# Key Vault ID Does Not Match Key Vault's True Resource ID

Tags: azure

Disclaimer - I am relatively green at most things Azure, but I'm trying to resize an Azure VM, but getting the error below. The key vault is enabled for deployment.

The VM is in ResourceGroupB but the Key Vault is in a different resource group. I'm not sure how the Key Vault was ever associated with ResourceGroupB, or why the VM has made it some dependency to make any change.

I've been working with Azure support, but my tech is either more lost than I am or this is an uncommon occurrence. I'm hoping it's the prior. It's just not clear how to dissociate the vault from the VM.

I tried disabling the secret version in question but that had no effect. On instructions by the tech, I stopped the machine and now it will not come back up so I'm a bit desperate. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
Provisioning failed. Key Vault https://[NameOfKeyVault].vault.azure.net/secrets/[NameOfSecret]/[VersionGuid]
    either has not been enabled for deployment or the vault id provided, /subscriptions/[SubscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[ResourceGroupB]/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[NameOfKeyVault],
    does not match the Key Vault's true resource id.KeyVaultAccessForbidden
```

Comment: Have you checked the box to allow the key vault use for deployment?

Comment: @SamCogan Yes, deployment is enabled.